# Solve $Bx = [ 1 2 1 ]^T$ for each $k \in \{ 1, 2, -3 \}$?

Tags: matrices

Where $B$ is the matrix: 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &1 &k\\
2 &k &1 \\
k &2 &2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: I would swap rows so that the last becomes the first one. Then I'd apply Gauss' reduction.

Comment: Roxana, are you saying that you know how to bring a matrix to reduced row-echelon form, but that you don't know how to read off the solutions once you've done that?

Comment: Gerry, would I be right in saying that where k=1, x1+x4=0 and x2+x3=0 so that there are infinitely many solutions but there are no solutions where k=2 and k=-3?

Comment: @Roxana Why do you have four unknowns?

Comment: Sorry, would x1=1 and x2+x3=0 be correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct for $k=1$. If you want to be sure I see a comment directed to me, you have to write @Gerry.

Answer (score 1):

The determinant of $B$ is $$-6+7k-k^3.$$ Hence $B$ is singular for $k \in \{-3,1,2\}$. By Cramer's rule, the unknown $x_1$ is indetermined if $k=1$, since
$$
\det 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &1 &k \\
2 &k &1 \\
1 &2 &2
\end{pmatrix}
=0
$$
when $k=1$ (and $k=5$, but we do not care). Hence you have infinitely many solutions for $k=1$.

If you try to solve for $x_2$ and $x_3$, you will see that no solutions can exist for $k=-3$ or $k=2$.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up, the explanation was helpful